# why cannot javascript execute methods inside methods?

Tags: javascript, methods, functional-programming

In functional languages functions can execute inside the argument brackets of nested functions what is the equivalent for javascript which is meant to be inspired by Scheme.

> > f( f ( f ( f)))

```
console.log( 1 + 1 )
//2
```

how come javascript can execute addition inside the `.log` method argument parentheses?

```
var list1 = []
console.log(list1.push("a"))
//1
```

yet it cannot execute the push method inside the `.log` method parentheses? and why does it return 1?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `Array.prototype.push`?

Comment: Your main question doesn't make sense to me. It returns 1 because push returns the length of the array you've inserted element to. It does push element to the array, but as you're logging the return of push, and not the list1 you see only 1. If you'll log `console.log(list1.push("a"), list1)` you'll see that that your array has `a` in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`push`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) returns the size of the array:

> The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns
>   the new length.

**It does execute the push function, it's just not returning what you were expecting.**

JavaScript was [written in only 10 days](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/A_Short_History_of_JavaScript) so we are stuck with some design decisions. It's amazing that we even get as much functional style as we do (since marketing people wanted a "Java-like" language).

JavaScript enables one to write in a functional way, but there may be some roadblocks.

[This quote](https://m.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3z6nll/how_did_javascript_turn_out_to_be_a_toy_language/) is interesting:

> Luckily Eich managed to sneak some great ideas into the language
>   despite what he was asked to do.

It is also not totally clear-cut whether it would be better for `push` to return the array `length` or what you had just pushed, or the whole array reference...etc.

Answer (score 5):

The `push` method returns the new length property of the object it modified.

> Returns: 
>   The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

Answer (score 2):

Your .push method is getting executed, but you are seeing 1 because push returns the new length of the array. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push